# background getWidth based on mouse position

Tags: java

what does /2 - 5 in the java  code  below mean also what does `if(mX >= 0 && mX >= 0)` mean thanks

```
 /*The program draws a circle when mouse is clicked on right side the background becomes red and on left side the 
 background becomes pink. with a vertical line  in the middle of screen.*/

// below is a section of the full code    

// verify whether the mouse position is valid
if(mX >= 0 && mX >= 0) {      
   // draw the circle
   g.fillOval(mX, mY, 10, 10);  

   // set the background color based on the mouse position
   if(mX < getWidth() / 2 - 5)
      setBackground(Color.RED);
   else
      setBackground(Color.PINK);
}
```

Comment: `(mX >= 0 && mX >= 0)` is completly redundant, maybe it should have been `(mX >= 0 && mY >= 0)`. `if(mX < getWidth() / 2 - 5)` is a comparison if mX is lower than the width divded by 2 minus 5.

Answer (score 0):

Your code extends a View class (like Button, Label or something). `getWitdh()` gives your View's width. `If width = 50 (getWidth() / 2 - 5)` gives you 20.
mX and mY are just variables, probably earlier in the class/function they get mouse's x and y coordinates.

This part draws a circle and if mouse x position is lower than `(getWidth() / 2 - 5)` then view becomes red, else it becomes pink of course.

Comment: is there a purpose for the  -5  in (getWidth() / 2 - 5)

Comment: probably the view at 0,0 point. and circle's radius is 5. Width(10) minus 5 gives the X position of circles center.